# Finding prime numbers with Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in c

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to find the first 1000 prime numbers using an algorithm called "Sieve of Eratosthenes"
Basically, you have a list of ascending numbers 2,3,4 ... and this list represents potential prime numbers; Number 2 is prime so it is printed, then, we check the list for any multiples of 2. If we find any, we omit them. And keep going till we have our correct list.

I thought of using nested loops for this one, and although I don't feel like it's a perfect idea; I don't see why it won't work. Here is my code. It doesn't run at all

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int primelist[999];
    int n = 2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        primelist[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++, n++)
    {
        while (primelist[i] != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
            {
            if ( (primelist[n] % primelist[i]) == 0 )
            {
                primelist[i] = 0;
            }
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Valid indicies for `primelist[999]` are 0..998. Access to `primelist[999]` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Either change  to `primelist[1000]` or use `i < 999`

Comment: `int i;` in the outer loop and `int i;` in the inner loop... Bound to cause confusion to humans, but not to the compiler... (PS: This, if it worked, would find 'n' primes in the first 1000 numbers, NOT the first 1000 prime numbers...)

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes **does** absolutely ***no*** **checking** for multiples. it enumerates them through addition, and marks them as composites.

Comment: See also [question 20.8](https://c-faq.com/misc/bitsets.html) in the [C FAQ list](https://c-faq.com/).